# How to update progress bar max with changing values automatically?

Tags: java, android

I am working on a fitness app using Google fit API.

Step data from the API is passed to a method `stepDisplayer` with e.g. params (3300, "steps").

I am trying to update the progress bar once `value == daily1` so that the max of bar is then `pbStepBar.setMax(daily2)` and again to `pbStepBar.setMax(daily3)` when `value == daily2`, while the progress of the bar is always set to value e.g. 3500/4000 then 4102/8000 and 8900/12000.

I tried to use a switch statement comparing the goals to value with a method called `setNextGoal(value)` with getter and setter methods `getCurrentGoal()` and `setCurrentGoal()` as seen below, but that did not work. Max value does not change from `daily1` when I run the application and it looks something like this 5050/4000.

What am I doing wrong? Can I replace `pbStepBar` with another progress bar and and switching visibility?

Layout

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbStepBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:scaleY="3"
        />



public class MainActivity {

//these are goals
int daily1 = 4000
int daily2 = 8000
int daily3 = 12000

//set to this onCreate
pbStepBar.setMax = daily1

private void stepDisplayer(final int value, final String field) {
    tvHomeSteps = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHomeSteps);
    pbStepBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.pbStepBar);
    setNextGoal(value);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tvHomeSteps.setText("today's " + field + " " + value + "/" + dailyStepGoal);
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (value <= getCurrentGoal()) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pbStepBar.setProgress(value);
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (getCurrentGoal() == value) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well done you reached your daily goal of " + getCurrentGoal() + " " + field,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                    });
                }

                setNextGoal(value);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}

private void setNextGoal (final int value) {
    switch (value) {

        case dailyStepGoal:
            setCurrentGoal(dailyStepGoal + stepGoalIncrement);
            pbStepBar.setMax(dailyStepGoal + stepGoalIncrement);
            break;

        case dailyStepGoal + stepGoalIncrement:
            setCurrentGoal(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*2));
            pbStepBar.setMax(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*2));
            break;

        case dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*2):
            setCurrentGoal(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*3));
            pbStepBar.setMax(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*3));
            break;

        case dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*3):
            setCurrentGoal(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*4));
            pbStepBar.setMax(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*4));
            break;

        case dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*4):
            setCurrentGoal(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*5));
            pbStepBar.setMax(dailyStepGoal + (stepGoalIncrement*5));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I used an int variable `currentGoal` as seen below to keep track of the current goal. I think the problem was that I was trying to call methods in the activity from the UI thread. I used a simple if statement, don't know why I didn't think of this earlier.

I also tested the solution it works well.

private void stepDisplayer(final int value, final String field) {

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (value >= currentGoal) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Well done you reached your daily goal of " + currentGoal + " " + field,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                currentGoal += stepGoalIncrement;
                tvHomeSteps.setText("today's " + field + " " + value + "/" + currentGoal);
            }
            else {
                tvHomeSteps.setText("today's " + field + " " + value + "/" + currentGoal);
            }
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (value <= currentGoal) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        pbStepBar.setProgress(value);

                        if (value >= pbStepBar.getMax()) {
                            pbStepBar.setMax(currentGoal);
                            pbStepBar.setProgress(value);
                        }
                        else {
                            pbStepBar.setProgress(value);
                        }
                    }
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(25);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //setNextGoal(pbStepBar, value);
            }
        }
    }).start();
}
```